# Tools for network analysis in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst

I would like to do some cluster analysis. I created a clusters based on the distribution of points. Now I want to perform the next step, but I can't find the tool in ArcGIS Pro (name of the tool). I believe it is some kind of network analysis tool. Basically I want to know the distances and connections between each cluster. The example on the print screen shows what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are looking for the Point Distance tool in the Analysis Toolbox. [To get distances between points in the same layer, use that layer as both in features and near features](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/point-distance.htm#:%7E:text=Distances%20between%20points%20within%20the,the%20input%20and%20near%20features.&text=The%20table%20containing%20the%20list,features%20within%20the%20search%20radius.).